# Why do sensible questions get voted down, deleted etc

Tags: discussion

I've spent 3 hours trying to post one simple query about a bizarre error message and happening in Xcode.

I've had the question when rewritten voted down and then put on hold for being "vague"

I wrote it again in the simplest most obvious way. I was flagged for writing a possible duplicate of the 'on hold' question!!

I clearly don't yet understand this site. I myself find new problems that no-one as yet understands worth sharing.

Comment: can we have ONE mod who knows ALL the techs we deal with enough to understand ALL posts? sorry, but nope (not mentioning that person would still be human, and have too little time for the job it would need to do). The fact you post again and again without trying to understand WHY it might not be on topic or correct here doesn't help your case. But honestly, checking your question, seems like you say "I have this weird error message, what do I do now". We need more info to fix this. You'll need to isolate what makes this happen a little bit more

Comment: If you were asking the same thing, why did you create a new question rather than editing the previous one?

Comment: Time is fine. I'll wait days if necessary. Downgrading / putting question on hold / calling new version a duplicate of on hold version. There are no ways of comprehending these actions.

Comment: jon I edited the other one three times till it was 100% clear. It was put on hold. That's why I had to write a new question. I don't ask for magic.. just rational, fair behaviour.

Comment: @Splish there's been a number of comments on your questions about people saying "we need more info to isolate your problem". You just keep on posting the same thing, saying "you should not downvote or put question on hold".... Did you try addressing what people tell you to try and improve? Check the comment from Ben Kane on your question on hold. He tells you EXACTLY what you should include.

Comment: Until *you thought* it was 100% clear; evidently, others disagree. *"That's why I had to write a new question"* - getting put on hold **does not** stop you continuing to edit it, indeed note that the banner asks you to do so. *"There are no ways of comprehending these actions"* - really? Your question is a blatant duplicate, how can you not understand that it would be marked as such? *"I don't ask for magic"* - actually, your question pretty much does.

Comment: If you are talking about this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289601/self-zooming-ipad-stops-debugging then I can see why they marked it as unclear.  It is hard to read and understand.

Comment: I want to know if anyone has seen this error message / behaviour ever. End of. No more information is needed to ask this. No-one needs make any response if they have not heard of it. When I sought an answer I found no information. This is hardly surprising if anybody else with the same question had it buried too. Open honest collaborative enquiry!!

Comment: Your questions are incredibly vague; you may not understand how we don't see your question as being clear, but rest assured, we don't understand how you think your question is acceptable.  Take the current incarnation of your question, you ask `I'm only asking if anyone has ever seen or heard of the error message`  So, then, the only acceptable answer from someone is "Yes" or "No, I've never seen that" from 15 people?  That's a completely inappropriate question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Questions that **only** contain an error message are not normally well received. People want to see exactly what you did to get the error, which typically means that you need to provide code that shows how the error is reproduced.

Comment: "Has anyone seen this error message" is incredibly vague?

Comment: There are many many questions on SO simply listing an error message receiving clear answers Reto

Comment: @Splish are these recent questions? or are these historical questions we decided do not fit our format over time? Honestly, try to take a breather, go calmly, and then read this from another point of view. You're SERIOUSLY just looking for "yes", "no", or "I have no clue" with NO idea on how to solve this? it's not implied that whoever comes with a "yes I've had that behavior" should explain how he got rid of it? If someone explains how to fix, it might not be appropriate because it might not fit your config (since we don't know your config...), hence the "unclear"

Comment: LittleBobbyTales there is no reason for people who haven't come across the error to say anything at all. Let alone downgrade/delete or put it on hold.

Do you genuinely think that if anyone else had experienced this error or Xcode behaviour that they would simply respond 'Yes'?

Comment: @Splish you have to be aware stack exists to build a good repository of questions and answers for OTHER users visiting. If you don't include anything about your config, chances are no one will ever find your question useful, since no one can relate to it.

Comment: @Splish So you're saying that you don't actually expect anyone to answer the question you actually asked, and you're expecting them to answer some question that you haven't actually asked?  And you wonder why people felt your question was unclear...

Comment: `Do you genuinely think that if anyone else had experienced this error or Xcode behaviour that they would simply respond 'Yes'?` No, but only because there's a 30 character limit when answering.  Otherwise, "Yes"

Comment: No @Patrice I'm looking on a collaborative community for people who may be able to share with me similar experiences of problems. And of course I don't want people to just respond 'no'!! 

It's very simple. Xcode put out an error and zoomed the iPad when building/running a project.

If I go into a crowded room and say "is anyone a doctor" I'm not expecting all those who aren't a doctor to say "no" and I'm not expecting someone who is to say "yes" then walk away.

Comment: You do know that this is not a tutorial site

Comment: LittleBobbyTales, conversations, collaborations, exchanges, contacts, start with a short answer. In computer terms it's called handshaking. And 30 characters? What kind of game is this?

Comment: @Splish *"If I go into a crowded room and say "is anyone a doctor"..."* - that's actually a good example. If you walk into a crowded room and ask *"is anyone a doctor"*, you may well find that some of the people present say *"well I'm not a doctor, but I have some medical knowledge and if you give me some detail about the symptoms I may be able to help"*.

Comment: @Splish "when building/running a project".... that's not simple at all. that's actually SUPER vague. Did you try a blank, empty project with minimal code? does it reproduce? if not, include your code step by step and try to see WHEN you break it.  30 characters is not a game, it's the minimum length of an answer. Seems like you just complain about stack without really understanding the workings of the site...

Comment: That's right Santiago. It's not a tutorial site. People don't go to a tutorial site with unusual experiences with Xcode. This is supposed to be a collaborative community.

Comment: Oy - Stack Overflow isn't for conversations, collaborations, exchanges, chats, discussions, tête-à-têtes or dialogues, it's for asking, and getting answered, concrete programming questions, which your questions don't seem to be, because you seemingly refuse to provide ample information, or follow any of the guidelines of SO.

Comment: @Splish it is a Question and Answer site, not a "collaborative community" - which sounds like a forum, which SO is not

Comment: @Patrice It is not vague in the slightest. It makes no difference whatsoever what my code is (and of course a blank template doesn't reproduce it- its a project with 10s of thousands of lines of code)

It's simple. Am I the only one to have seen this error ? If I'm alone - fine. I'll keep working on it on my own as i did the last few 100 problems. If someone else has experienced it - we'll talk.

But there is  no justification for those who can't help downgrading, deleting and putting on hold my flag. It means anyone else who's experienced this error will find the same blank wall I've found.

Comment: @Patrice 
And yes I didn't know there was a minimum 30 character answer. I'm a newbie to posting questions. But I'm an intelligent guy looking for honest collaborative people with integrity and a positive attitude. You are no doubt aware of the reputation of SO. An email from a senior member to me today described it as a 'rough place'. What a shame :( It could be so much more.

Comment: littleBobbyTales Here is a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334178/lost-connection-to-ipad-2#26487325 It got dealt with intelligently.

Comment: New members, just like all members, have to abide by the quality standards for Stack Overflow

Comment: @Splish *"If someone else has experienced it - we'll talk"* - that does not sound like the kind of interaction the Q&A model encourages. *"You are no doubt aware of the reputation of SO"* - the largest and most successful programming resource on the internet? *"But I'm an intelligent guy looking for honest collaborative people with integrity and a positive attitude"* - practice what you preach, please. The example question you've found is also shit, the OP just got lucky. You've been told what's needed to get the question reopened; either provide it or go away, this "discussion" is pointless.

Comment: In fact @Patrice its 15

Comment: @Splish I just tried posting here an answer and "body must be 30". Anyway, as I said, config/code DO matter. Stack is not a forum, it's a Q&A site. a Q should be self-contained and answered in a single A. If people come in, giving you "yes I encountered, I just disabled the flubboxed library and it worked" and you say "well I don't use the flubboxed library....". Do you understand why people say that this is unclear? we have a symptom of a problem, but no idea what the problem actually is. Stack is NOT meant for discussion, and isn't a forum.

Comment: @santiago Quality standards would be good. Explain who this question is ok and mine is not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334178/lost-connection-to-ipad-2#26487325

Comment: @Splish and you say you're looking for feedback and all. People tell you "to follow our guidelines, you should consider including this" why don't you stop stomping your feet and listen to what we tell you. As usual, posting OTHER questions saying "but this passed" is not a good idea, since yes, sometimes, crap gets through. Chances are the extra attention you brought on that crap question means it'll get DVed/possibly put on hold soon

Comment: @Splish Care to comment on what several people have told you now and that you've thus far ignored? About this site not being meant for collaboration, and you specifically looking for collaboration?

Comment: @Patrice Sometimes two heads are better than one. Sometimes two angles give a better view. A Q does not always have a single simple answer on this site of course.

The fact is - no-one has come across this before except http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936547/connection-was-interrupted-to-zoom-ui-server-in-xcode-running-on-device/31219526#31219526 - and I thought he was unlucky to be just ignored!!

Comment: @Clive Yes I don't mind commenting. I'm not looking for 'collaboration'I'm looking for answers to programming problems. In this case - no-one has ever heard of this problem before except http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936547/connection-was-interrupted-to-zoom-ui-server-in-xcode-running-on-device/31219526#31219526 Instead of keeping quiet and letting the problem remain for others to search, many have tried to erase the problem away as - as Patrice calls it - a crap question. I'm not impressed.

Comment: You mentioned several times in the comments on _this_ question that you're looking for "collaboration", that's why I ask. You're looking for a back-and-forth to help you zone in on a bug either in your code or your IDE. What we're telling you is that the kind of interaction you want isn't supported here, you need to do that leg work yourself. What you're telling us is that you're not interested, that you think you should be able to have your collaborative style interaction. As you say, you're a newbie. Why try to dictate the rules before you know how this is supposed to work?

Comment: (I mean no hostility by the way, I see this kind of argument on meta pretty frequently and it always seems pretty obvious to me: go by the rules, and you'll be fine; don't, and you won't. I never really understand why there's more to be said about these things)

Comment: @Splish for OUR quality standards, yes it is a crap question (doesn't mean it's BAD, means it's BAD FOR THIS SITE). Stack's standards are not necessarily instinctive or easy to abide by, but they are what makes this community so popular. You can fight back, or you can try to understand the system, work WITH it, and after a while, suggest improvements. Right now, you just seem like another of these meta users who will just complain and stomp without listening.

Comment: I appreciate your time Clive. I am a newbie to SO. I don't want to dictate anything. I searched the entire web for this error message and found it in only on SO. I'd love to talk to that guy - but there's no way it seems.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936547/connection-was-interrupted-to-zoom-ui-server-in-xcode-running-on-device/31219526#31219526

Comment: @Patrice I know it seems that way but I have listened and do appreciate all the continued attempts you've made to communicate.  I can't pretend to fully understand why my question had to be quashed but I'm certainly willing to learn.

Comment: @Splish You can withdraw my statement about the stomping then :). We DO get a lot of those users and it's aggravating. If I ended up sounding abrasive, I do apologize (I did think you'd be one of these users and turned defensive :S). For your current conundrum, you'll have to try creating a minimal example (if your project has thousands of line, it'll be a pain...  but if no one knows the answer, the work will have to be done :S, and maybe doing it will simply help you figure it out yourself? ). Anyway, welcome to the community. I hope I didn't turn you off from this site :).

Comment: @Patrice Thanks. No. Not turned off. I've had a poor first day but I hope to share the positive side of my tenaciousness on future occasions.

Comment: Keep persevering @Splish, it is a bit of a learning curve, but you'll get there

Answer (score 7):

> There should be an appeal system.

There is, and you have used it. Meta.SO exists for people to bring issues to the attention of the community, as you have done here. Moderators and community members can read the issues brought up here and respond to or act on them.

Per your questions, what happened was this: you first posted a question in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31219526/19679) that consisted of the text:

> Anyone have any clues?
>
> I'm getting this every time I build now. The iPad self zooms and the
>   build stops with this error.
>
> !!

That didn't actually answer the question asked, and there was no way for anyone to answer you there, so it was flagged by the community. drescherjm left a comment to that effect, and asked you to ask an actual question. (They were only [one of six reviewers who voted to delete](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8679387), as that's an action typically handled by community review.)

You then did so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31289601/revisions), but your original version consisted largely of a digression about your original non-answer and SO policy. I believe that people downvoted based on that, since it obscured your actual issue.

Your new question probably received downvotes because it was a restated duplicate of your original.

Reading your newly revised question, you might still need to provide some more details. I'm not sure that we have enough information to reproduce this to diagnose the issue. With that additional detail, it could be a good question.

To be more specific: what you're experiencing seems to be an Xcode bug. From the lack of other search results for "Connection was interrupted to zoom UI server", I'm assuming it's a new one and is triggered by something uncommon (it's not one that I've seen personally in my iPad development work). Therefore, the specific Xcode version, iOS deployment target, and details about what your project is doing are going to be necessary to even start to diagnose this. Think about what you'd need to have in a bug report for a rare bug in one of your own applications, or what Apple would want to be specified in a Radar.

Comment: Thanks Brad. My first day on SO. Feel like I've been through the mangle but I'll try to learn.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to answer my own question by saying that the questioner (myself) has been slow at grasping the nature of this site.

This is my first day attempting to participate properly.

Many fruitful visits to SO over the months should have taught me that this site works well.

Rather than attempting to change the way things are - rather than challenging literally every other responder, the questioner would have been wiser to catch on quicker as to what it has been about this site (example code etc...) that has been so useful to him.

I can understand if this response gets downgraded itself. Brad's response covered the ground fully.

Nonetheless I'd like to thank all who have persevered in communicating with me and apologise for using up valuable time.

I'll waste no more.

Comment: Not a waste of time at all, judging by this very positive answer. Nothing to apologise for either!

Comment: We recognize that many of the rules of the site are very different from other places on the Internet, and that can take a little getting used to. As long as you don't hold any hard feelings for what happened, and you understand how to improve things going forward, this was all worth the time. Don't feel bad about it.